# Using PyCharm with QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, pycharm

I've just changed to QGIS 3 and I can't figure out why I can't change from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6 in PyCharm, keep getting invalid SDK!
I run this `.bat`-file:

```py
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\bin\pycharm64.exe"

CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat

SET PATH=%PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
SET PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figure it out!

`CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat` called on all .bat files in `%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\etc\ini\` and there is the file: `python-core.bat`

So by changing from python27 to python36 in `C:\osgeo4w64\etc\ini\python-core.bat` Pycharm find all dependencies :)

EDIT 2018-02-19:
After a while away from qgis-master I went back today and had some problems with getting Pycharm working, then I found [this post](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis3-on-windows/)! Really nice and updated!

Comment: There is no need to change anything from QGIS batch files because it will create complications. You can simply add a `SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python36` line to your batch file and it will change Python26 to 36 or 37 in some versions.