# PyQGIS standalone app with pycharm : exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, pycharm

I try to run standalone PyQgis code with PyCharm, but I always have this result :

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I tried my code line by line, and this result appear after the last :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QMainWindow
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

I use PyCharm 2018.3.6 (Community Edition), because [issues on 2019 version occured](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317332/pycharm-2019-is-not-working-with-qgis-anymore).
Qgis 3.6 with OSGeo4W.

My .cmd code :

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qt5_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\py3_env.bat

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
SET GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.6\bin\pycharm64.exe"

set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%

set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins\platforms
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM%
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you setting up your pycharm env: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251851/using-pycharm-with-qgis-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just replace

```
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```

by

```
app = QApplication([])
qgs = QgsApplication([],False)
qgs.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
qgs.initQgis()
```

It's work !